# MS Access 2010 VBA - What is the SourceObjectType for a local table?

Tags: vba, ms-access, linked-tables

The table I am copying is a linked table. I want the new table to be a local table.
My existing code is:

```
Private Sub CmdOpenTable_Click()
      DoCmd.CopyObject , "Scheme_copy", acTable, "dbo_scheme"    
End Sub
```

Can I change the sourceobject type in bold above to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

No, that will copy the *object*, nothing more.

To convert to a local table, *import* the linked table with `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` .

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, `SELECT * INTO MyLocalTable FROM MyLinkedTable` tends to work too.

Comment: I have imported table "Dave" from "dbo_scheme" using below, but it is still linked. Is that because source table is linked? can you help me localize?

       DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", "F:\Access Databases\home\Daily Scheme Table Home.accdb", acTable, "dbo_scheme", "Dave"

Comment: Yes. You must import the source table of that link, not the link.